# How to stop jetty runner from executing

Tags: jetty

Am using jettyrunner for executing my war files.I am using command java -jar jetty runner ex.war.But am running this jetty server from my java application by executing this commands from java.My problem is at first time its working good,but the second time if i am again executing another war file with the same code its executing the older war.i have found the reason that the older jetty server is keep on running.How could i stop this server from java in order to start the jetty server for another war.

Answer (score 2):

One option should be:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Secure_Termination

Another would be to use the ShutdownHandler:

http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/ShutdownHandler.java

Or don't use the jetty-runner directly like that from java code and just write a small embedded usage:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty

Comment: Secure_Termination article is good, it explains how to start jetty-runner with stop-port and stop-key but id doesn't explain how to stop it.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out, jetty-runner.jar doesn't have a feature to stop existing jetty process ran with `stop-port` and `stop-key`.

I found the answer in https://github.com/jetty-project/jetty-documentation/blob/master/src/docbkx/administration/runner/jetty-runner.xml

> Then, to stop jetty from a different terminal, you need to
>             supply the same port and key information. For this you'll either
>             need a local installation of jetty, the `jetty-maven-plugin` `jetty-ant` plugin, or write a custom class

Fortunately, I was implementing gradle build, so `jetty-ant` satisfied my needs.